# Why there is a 'FROM weeks' at the end of this postgresql code

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I don't understand why there is another `FROM weeks` code at the end of this snippet. Is this wrong code?. I don't know how it work.

```
WITH weeks AS (
  SELECT make_interval(weeks => n) as week 
  from generate_series(0, 3) AS n
)
SELECT week, 
       count(x.user_email) as "Returning Users"
FROM weeks
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT act.user_email, age(act.timestamp, acc.timestamp) as diff
     FROM accounts acc
       JOIN action act on act.user_email = acc.user_email
  ) x ON x.diff >=  week and diff < week + '1 week'::interval
FROM weeks
GROUP BY week;
```

The code is taken from this link:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/258610/optimizing-a-user-retention-query/258611#258611

I don't have 50 reputation to comment at that page, so i ask here

Comment: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"`  So yes, something is wrong with it.  Since I don't know what it is supposed to do, it is hard to say what exactly the problem is.

Comment: The second `FROM weeks` is an error. I'm guessing a copy and paste mistake from the original question query where the answerer  inserted the ` count  ...FROM weeks LEFT JOIN ...`  between the original `week,` and `FROM weeks`.

Comment: The second FROM weeks (just above the GROUP BY) is wrong and should be removed.